What defines collaborative filtering?
What is the defining feature of collaborative filtering?
If you take two embedding vectors (one for a user and one for an item), you can do a dot-product and pass the result to a sigmoid function to predict CTR. Is this collaborative filtering?
Alternatively, you can put a number of FC layers on each embedding and then do a dot-product. Is this collaborative filtering?
You can also concatenate a number of discrete and continuous features to each embedding, then pass them to FC layers and do sigmoid. Is this collaborative filtering?

You did look up the definition with an internet search before asking this question?

@CliffAB there might be caveats with this (potentially interesting) question, but an interest in those should be clearly stated in the question.

@CliffAB the OP ask for a definition without saying what's wrong with the definitions found in standard texts (without good explanation, the answer is simply copy-paste from a standard textbook). The examples like 'pass the result to a sigmoid function' are not very clear what is meant by it. It will depend on how that function had been trained (using data from the larger population or not).

@CliffAB a problem with the question is that it simply asks for a definition, something that the first paragraphs from the Wikipedia page that your answer links to already explains. The question does not speak about confusion, something that is your interpretation of the question (you might be right, or even when you are not then stil your interpretation makes an interesting question) but this stuff should be spelled out in the question. We can not leave this open to interpretation (especially since the question is HNQ which will attract all kinds of answers with different interpretation).

How is computing a cross product of a user and item vector and applying a sigmoid collaborative filtering? Or is it the training of the embedding model, with multiple users/items that you see as the collaborative part?

@CliffAB it sounds like MF, but just the fact that some cross product is computed doesn't make it CF. You can define vectors and make cross products without 'using relation between viewers interests'. So you assumed that the question was about the distinction narrow/broad in definitions of collaborative filtering. But possibly the question is about understanding why matrix factorisation is considered collaborative filtering (as the description in the question is not very colorful with just the application of a function $\frac{1}{1+e^{Y\cdot X}}$, important is how those vectors were obtained).

Could you spell out the acronyms CTR and FC by editing the post? Thank you.

@CliffAB You had an interesting answer but the question was confusing. I believe that it could be nice to create a question of your own, then add your answer to it. My criticism was mostly about the question but leaked out to your answer.

funny- some guy who does not seem to understand what MF is comments on whats CF and shut down the question and the author who posted the correct answer had to delete all replies. wow

To quote directly from Search Engines: Information Retrieval in Practice (2009) by Croft et al.:
"Filtering that considers the relationship between profiles (or between users) and uses this information to improve how incoming items are matched to profiles. (or users) is called collaborative filtering".
Where "filtering" here means the identification of relevant new items and their presentation to a user. Effectively Collaborative Filtering (CF) is an imputation-like task where having observed a  (usually tiny) subset of the matrix $X$ which holds ratings, viewing times, etc. we want to predict missing values of $X$ (usually for new users) and pick the values associated the outcome we want (e.g. highest rating). That is what contrasts CF to say a content-based filtering systems where we learn what users like based on the descriptions of the items recommended.
Coming now back to the original question, nothing regarding CF is particular to Click-Through-Rates, the use of sigmoids, embeddings, dot-products, fully connected or average pooling layers. These are implementation details. The defining feature of CF is that the recommendations provided are based on what other users are rating/consuming.

"The defining feature of CF is that the recommendations provided are based on what other users are rating/consuming." => Most recommendation system in production today use these features. Yet most claim that they are far more advanced than CF. I feel like your definition is a bit broad.

Yes, the definition is a bit broad and you are correct that "most recommendation system in production today use these features", CF has proven very successful. That said, what we see in productions often are extensions (e.g. in terms of using time-varying/exogenous variables, custom loss functions, regularisation methods, etc.) Those are indeed "far more advanced than" say ALS-based CF which is with us for 15+ years but ultimately solve the same problem using the same rationale and (mostly) the basic features. It is a bit of a ship of Theseus situation but ultimately it is still a ship!
